# Multiple pub/sub subscribers in one application

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to set up two different google pub/sub subscribers to different subscriptions but in the same code. To paint a better picture say I have topic1 and topic2. Then I have subscription1 which is subscribed to topic1 and subscription2 which is subscribed to topic2. Then I have subscriber1 which is linked to subscription1 and subscriber2 which is linked to subscription2. My question is how can I use subscriber1 and subscriber2 in the same application. My example for just 1 subscriber is (from documentation):

```
project_id = "my-project-id"
subscription_id = "subscription1"

subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_id)
streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
logging.info("Listening for messages on {}..\n".format(subscription_path))

# Wrap subscriber in a 'with' block to automatically call close() when done.
with subscriber:
    try:
        # When `timeout` is not set, result() will block indefinitely,
        # unless an exception is encountered first.
        streaming_pull_future.result()
    except TimeoutError:
        streaming_pull_future.cancel()
```

How can I add subscription2 into this so that my python application can get messages from both topic1 and topic2? I couldn't find it in the docs but if I'm just missing it somehow let me know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to receive messages from two subscriptions at the same time, you create two SubscriberClient instances, one for each subscription. To combine the futures, you could use an Event:

```
project_id = "my-project-id"
subscription_id1 = "subscription1"
subscription_id2 = "subscription2"

subscriber1 = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscriber2 = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path1 = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_id1)
subscription_path2 = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_id2)
streaming_pull_future1 = subscriber1.subscribe(subscription_path1, callback=callback)
logging.info("Listening for messages on {}.".format(subscription_path1))
streaming_pull_future2 = subscriber2.subscribe(subscription_path2, callback=callback)
logging.info("Listening for messages on {}.".format(subscription_path2))

subscriber_shutdown = threading.Event()
streaming_pull_future1.add_done_callback(lambda result: subscriber_shutdown.set())
streaming_pull_future2.add_done_callback(lambda result: subscriber_shutdown.set())

# Wrap subscriber in a 'with' block to automatically call close() when done.
with subscriber1, subscriber2:
  subscriber_shutdown.wait()
  streaming_pull_future1.cancel()
  streaming_pull_future2.cancel()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So this is where I'm having trouble, I know how to create the two SubscriberClient instances but how can I open both of them at the same time using the ```with``` syntax?

Comment: I updated the answer with some code that might help.

Comment: Perfect, the code you provided helped me make it work. Cheers!